# Creating new log in accounts via an admin page - form data saved to text file

Tags: php

As you can probably guess, I am new to learning PHP and have an assignment to create a page where new user accounts can be created by entering the username and password into form fields, which then needs to be saved in a text document.

I have spent hours trying to figure this out and have tried what I have seen suggested on other questions. As I mentioned previously, I am very new to this and need to keep things basic.

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    $newUsername = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST["newuser"]));
    $newPassword = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST["newpwd"]));
    $file = "user_accounts.txt";

    $openfile = fopen($file, "a") or die("Unable to open file");

    if($newUsername || $newPassword == ""){
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Error: Please complete all fields")';
        echo '</script>';}

    else{
        fwrite ($openfile, "$newUsername \n $newPassword \n");
        fclose($openfile);}

}
?>
```

And here is my form code:

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">        
    Username: <input type="text" name="user"><br> 
    Password: <input type="password" name="pwd"><br> 
    <input type="submit"> 
</form>
```

Comment: The issue I am having is that it just keeps throwing up the error, even though the form fields are not blank.

Comment: `$var || $var == ""` is NOT going to do what you think it is: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: Its not? :( I'm trying to make sure they aren't blank. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: You need to check that both of them are not blank `$newUsername == "" || $newPassword == ""`

Comment: @charlotterose23 You have alot of good answers here... What test data are you using in the forms? Any strange characters... multibyte or non UTF-8? `htmlspecialchars()` will return a blank result if the character set is wonky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is this:

`if($newUsername || $newPassword == "")` is missing `== ""` for `$newUsername`

*Plus*, your input form element names don't match.

`$_POST["newuser"]` with `name="user"` does not match.

`$_POST["newpwd"]` and `name="pwd"` does not match.

Tested:

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    $newUsername = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST["newuser"]));
    $newPassword = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST["newpwd"]));
    $file = "user_accounts.txt";

    $openfile = fopen($file, "a") or die("Unable to open file");

    if($newUsername == "" || $newPassword == ""){
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Error: Please complete all fields")';
        echo '</script>';}

    else{
        fwrite ($openfile, "$newUsername \n $newPassword \n");
        fclose($openfile);}

}
?>

<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">        
    Username: <input type="text" name="newuser"><br> 
    Password: <input type="password" name="newpwd"><br> 
    <input type="submit"> 
</form>
```

---

**Footnotes:**

I suggest you change this line:

```
fwrite ($openfile, "$newUsername \n $newPassword \n");
```

to

```
fwrite ($openfile, "$newUsername\n$newPassword \n");
```

because it is adding a space (*when testing*) at the end of the user name and at the beginning (*and at the end*) of each password in the file itself, and this could have consequences in regards to character matching.

```
fwrite ($openfile, "$newUsername \n $newPassword \n");
                                ^               ^
```

Another thing is, using this type of system is considered unsafe unless you are properly hiding it outside of the public realm and/or using `.htaccess`

Using a DB is safer.

Comment: Oh yay it has worked! Instead of if(($newUsername == "") || ($newPassword == "")){ I used if($newUsername == "" || $newPassword == ""){ :D Thank you so much!

Comment: You're very much welcome. Did you look at my **footnotes** also? @charlotterose23 It did that when testing. Not sure if you wanted that or not.

Comment: Also consider clicking the White checkmark till it turns Green next to my answer to be marked as solved. That way it won't remain as unanswered. (*It's also a way to say thanks*) ;-) @charlotterose23 Cheers

Comment: Yes, thank you. I had just gone into the file and noticed the spaces and had changed it but thank you for pointing it out too. Now to find this checkmark... lol

Comment: I know its very insecure - its for a college assignment and this is what I have been asked to do!

Comment: It's under the arrows to the left. @charlotterose23 I also made another edit for security purposes also, if you want to reload it.

Comment: You see an up and down arrow where there's already a `1`? It's right under there; kind of hard to see. SO should work on that lol @charlotterose23

Comment: It's kind of a gray outlined checkmark under the big arrows next to my answer @charlotterose23

Comment: Ah there you go! And welcome to StackOverflow! All the best @charlotterose23

Comment: Sorry I was looking for something different, I call it a tick lol I did find it tho :D

Comment: Not a problem, a "tick" it is then! @charlotterose23

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
if($newUsername || $newPassword == ""){
```

is parsed as:

```
if($newUsername || ($newPassword == "")){
                   ^--                ^--
```

and boils down to

```
if (true/false || true/false)
```

If username is filled in, you get

```
if (true || whatever)
```

and end up claiming there's an error.

You want

```
if (($newUsername == "") || ($newPassword == "")) {
```

instead

Comment: Thank you. I have changed this and it is still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

Your form fields have the name `user` and `pwd` respectively. However, in your PHP code you are looking for `newuser` and `newpwd`.

Try using `var_dump($_POST);` in your PHP code to help debug little typos like this. :-)

Comment: Ah thank you. I had spotted this and changed it but not on the live version. Its still not working though :( and I'm not sure about what var_dump does?

Comment: @charlotterose23 `var_dump` will give you a plain text representation of whatever you pass into it. `$_POST` is an array so it would show you a list of all the array keys, data types and values. It's helpful for checking to see if things are working the way you intended.

Answer (score 0):

The names of your inputs in the form translate into the variable names in the POST array.

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    $newUsername = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST["user"]));
    $newPassword = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST["pwd"]));
    $file = "user_accounts.txt";

    $openfile = fopen($file, "a") or die("Unable to open file");

    //note how these have changed - each condition is separated by ()
    if(($newUsername == "") || ($newPassword == "")){
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Error: Please complete all fields")';
        echo '</script>';
    } else {
        fwrite ($openfile, "$newUsername \n $newPassword \n");
        fclose($openfile);
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you. I have changed my code but for some reason it just won't work. Still giving me the error even though they are not blank!!

Comment: @charlotterose23 - which error? Unable to open file, or Error: Please complete all fields?

Answer (score 0):

$_POST["newuser"] with $_POST["user"] and $_POST["newpwd"] with $_POST["pwd"] in your php code.